# Customize Extensionpay payment page for chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So i am nearly finished my chrome extension and in order to set up a monthly subscript, I incorporated [Extensionpay](https://extensionpay.com/). When my extension is first downloaded, it has a signup page, which when clicked takes you to Extensionpays payment page, which looks as follows: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuqSE.png)

For anyone whose worked with extensionpay in the past, or just know of any solution thatd be great!

Question: How to edit extensionpays payment page?